# Cocoa Touch - Timing button presses

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm making  a reaction type game and I needed some help implementing a way to define who touched it first.

So I can compare and know who is the winner and award points correctly. I have no idea how im gonna implement this...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple buttons on your screen, the easiest way is probably to keep track of all the button presses (UITouch events) you get in the order you receive them. Once you get all the button presses you're expecting, go through the ordered list of presses and assign points as necessary.

Comment: Theres no second or third place. Could I just lock it after i get one and save it in an `int` the player number?

Comment: Sure, that would work as well - didn't know whether you cared about people who weren't first.

Comment: alright ill look into it. In the game your first or your not.